# how to avoid the repeated code to increase the efficiency

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, datagridview, refactoring

I have a `DataGrid` view1 and a `ListView` and when ever I select the list view item(I am passing the `ListView` item into the query and populating the `DataGrid` view according that item)

I have wrote some code like this....

```
 private void listview_selectedindexchanged(object sender event args)
 {
     if (listview.SelectedItems.Count > 0 && listview.SelectedItems[0].Group.Name == "abc")
     {
            if(lstview.SelectedItems[0].Text.ToString() == "sfs")
            {
              method1();
            }
            else
            {
                // datagrid view1 binding
               blah.....
             }
     }
     if (lstview.SelectedItems.Count > 0 && lstview.SelectedItems[0].Group.Name == "def")
     {

           if(lstview.SelectedItems[0].Text.ToString() == "xyz")
           {
               method 1();
           }
           if(lstview.SelectedItems[0].Text.ToString() == "ghi")
           {
               method 2(a,b);
           }
           if(lstview.SelectedItems[0].Text.ToString() == "jkl")
           {
               method 2(c,d);
           }
           if(lstview.SelectedItems[0].Text.ToString() == "mno")
           {
               method 3();
           }

       }
   }  
private void method 1()
{ 
  // datagrid view1 binding
    blahh     
}
private void method 2(e,g)
{
  // datagrid view1 binding
  blah....blah..
}
private void method 3()
{

    // datagrid view1 binding
}
```

I have done it like above ... I think this is not an efficient way to do the coding.  and this code consisits of a lot of repeated lines, is there any way to refractor this code to a small bunch of code ......
in order improve the efficiency?

Any ideas and sample snippets for increasing code efficiency would be helpful to me ...

Many thanks in advance....

I am using c# and writting WinForms applications.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could save a delegate into the listview item. And call it when the encapsulating item gets selected. For example you would fill your listbox like this:

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem("abc");
item.Tag = new Delegate(method1);
lstview.Items.Add(item);
```

Now, when this item gets selected, you execute the method like so:

```
private void listview_selectedindexchanged(object sender event args)
{
    ((Delegate)lstview.SelectedItems[0].Tag)(); // this will execute method1 if the item with text "abc" gets selected
}
```

NOTE: ! have not tested this code, but something along those lines should work and you don't have to write the If-statement, you only have to construct the items correctly.

Also note that this may be a bit hard to read for someone new to this code.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily extract a new method to do the "datagrid view1 binding". This method is then called from all the methods that need to do the binding.

Comment: Other than that is there any possibility to reduce the list view selected items into a single function...

Comment: I am missing some information here (e.g. what are `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`?), but personally, I would create an interface with one method and classes that derive from that interface and put them into the list view. Put the contents of method1 etc. in the methods in the derived classed. However, I don't know if it makes sense in your case, but a big if..else block always tells you that you should think about creating a class hierarchy and let polymorphism figure out the correct method that needs to be called.